# Marketplace framework

Tags: framework

I need to quickly build C2C marketplace solutions, that allow users to exchange products and paid services. Like a freelance marketplace.

Main features are:

1. Profile for customer (orders history);
2. Profile for implementer (services, rating, orders history, feedbacks);
3. Categories for services, where freelancers can publish their profiles;
4. Deals implementation (place an order, chatting, close the order, dispute);
5. Private chats;
6. Payments between customers and implementers;
7. Paid access for implementers.

It would be great, if a framework would be written using Ruby on Rails, Node.js, React.

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) Have you looked at [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) - we have [a support site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) for it? It seems the obvious answer, although it is not written in Ruby (do you *really* need to change the source?). Failing that, you will almost certainly find you answer at [CMS matrix](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/) which is the go to site for all things CMS and has a good wizard to help you choose.